Running `objdump` on an intermediate cmake target
I'm cross-compiling and I have a collection of assembly language programs in many files.
I define a static library, libtop.a to contain them all...
add_library(top
  STATIC
    /path/to/one.S
    /path/to/two.S
    ...
    /path/to/ten.S
)

cmake will pass each source file separately through gcc to create intermediate object files, before using ar to assemble them into the final libtop.a.
To do this, cmake constructs intermediate files <build_dir>/path/to/top.dir/.../one.S.obj, and <build_dir>/path/to/top.dir/.../two.S.obj, etc.
Perfect. Everything so far is working brilliantly...
My issue is that I need to ADD some additional symbols to SOME of those intermediate files.  For example, I WANT to do something like this:
add_custom_command(
  TARGET <???ten.S.obj???>
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_OBJCOPY}" 
    ARGS "--add-symbol" "ten=.text:__ten_aarch64,function,global"
         "$<TARGET_FILE:<???ten.S???>>"
)

I cannot figure out the magic target name or any property of the source or the final library target that might help me. Using the intermediate name I get from "make help" down in the tree doesn't work (No TARGET).
Please note that if I perform my objcopy command on the libtop.a, I'll get lots of multiply-defined symbol errors since objcopy will add to ALL the separate symbol tables in the file.  Maybe there's a more clever objcopy command?
Maybe I need to compose libtop.a in pieces, handling the special symbols one at a time? For example, define a libten.a and libsix.a with extra symbols, and then create libtop.a by combining them all?
Edit:
I changed my CMakeLists.txt to do this:
add_library(ten
  OBJECT
    /path/to/ten.S
)
add_library(top
  STATIC
    /path/to/one.S
    /path/to/two.S
    ...
    $<TARGET_OBJECTS:ten>
)

... and then put my POST_BUILD add_custom_command on my intermediate object library.  I get this error:
CMake Error at ./path/to/CMakeLists.txt:46 (add_custom_command):
  Target "ten" is an OBJECT library that may not have PRE_BUILD, PRE_LINK,
  or POST_BUILD commands.

This limitation is documented on the page for add_library(), but someone complained about it seven years ago.
Edit2:

Moved my solution to an "answer" per @nega.
Thanks to @Tsyvarev as well.


CMake does have a concept of "object libraries". Maybe this is something you can exploit? I'm not sure. This is an interesting question

"... To do this, cmake constructs intermediate files" - But those files should be treated as internal for CMake implementation. As far as I understand, there is no way for add custom steps when compile a source file into the object one. You probably need to perform such compilation manually. For add a resulted object into the library, see e.g. that question.

@nega cmake doesn't allow POST_BUILD commands on OBJECT libraries (for some reason?).  See my "edit".

i suppose you could unbundle your library, tweak the object files you want, then re-bundle it.

@nega I think that's what my final solution did. I pasted it back in my question...

If that's working for you, make your solution an answer

@nega Done!  Thanks also Tsyvarev.

Okay, I don't love this, but because I couldn't put a POST_BUILD on an object library, I just manually created ANOTHER intermediate target using add_custom_command(). I then had to fiddle and make more targets and dependencies because everything is always trouble, and I just gave up on creating a useful list of targets created by my function and hard-coded it...
Anyway, here is my solution...
  # Create an object lib for one file, hack it with a custom command.
  # Create a dummy target so it can be added as a dependency of the top library.
  function(objlib symbol)
    add_library(${symbol}
      OBJECT
        /path/to/${symbol}.S
    )
    set(ofile "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_${symbol}.obj")
    add_custom_command(
      OUTPUT  ${ofile}
      DEPENDS ${symbol}
      COMMAND "${CMAKE_OBJCOPY}" 
        ARGS "--add-symbol" "${symbol}=.text:__${name}_aarch64,function,global"
             "$<TARGET_OBJECTS:${symbol}>" "${ofile}"
      VERBATIM
    )
    add_custom_target(_${symbol} DEPENDS ${ofile})
    add_dependencies(top _${symbol})
endfunction()

add_library(top
  STATIC
    /path/to/one.S
    /path/to/another.S
    ...
    # Note that "two" and "ten" are not here, in source or object form.
)

objlib(two)
objlib(ten)

# Here we ADD our hacked object files to the library manually.
add_custom_command(
  TARGET top
  POST_BUILD
  COMMAND "${CMAKE_AR}"
     ARGS "-r" "$<TARGET_FILE:top>"
          "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_two.obj"
          "${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/_ten.obj"

